# Can I use Offset and Match to find the MIN value in a range of results?

Tags: excel, match, excel-formula, offset, min

I have a workbook with 2 worksheets, `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`.

`Sheet1` has a value (product code) to look up, and an empty cell to fill:

```
A      B
A100
A200
B150
C3AB
```

`Sheet2` has a bunch of product codes and costs:

```
A      B
A100   35.00
A100   14.00
A100   50.00
A200   10.00
A200   12.00
etc, etc, etc
```

I'm using the following to find a match between worksheets and populate `column B` in `Sheet1`:

```
=IFERROR(OFFSET(Sheet2!$B$1,MATCH(A1,Sheet2!$A:$A,0)-1,0), "")
```

Can I throw a `MIN` in there somewhere to pull out the lowest value in `column B` of `Sheet2`?

Comment: Can you sort column B in sheet2? That would solve your problem...

Comment: Not really as the sheet2 contains much more than I'm showing in my example. It's basically sorted by column A.

Comment: sorry, I meant sort it by Column A and then column B. would that be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Put this array formula in `B1` of `Sheet1` and press <kbd>CTL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

```
=MIN(IF(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5=A1,Sheet2!$B$1:$B$5))
```

I am assuming that your data range in `Sheet2` is from `A1:B5`. Change as applicable.

**ScreenShot**

[image]

Comment: Is there any issue with using =MIN(IF(Sheet2!A:A=A1,Sheet2!B:B)) to specify entire columns?

Comment: As long as you are using Excel 2007 or later version you can use whole columns......but it might slow the formulas, better to use a finite range if you can

Comment: Thanks .. the range may expand as data is added and I was trying to avoid the formula not working if someone just copy/pasted it.

Comment: Is there a way to have this ignore a 0 as the MIN value?

Comment: I tried =MIN(IF((Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5>0)*(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5=A1),Sheet2!$B$1:$B$5)) but that doesn't work (still returns the 0)

Comment: if MIN = 0, then show the 2nd lowest value. Basically, just exclude MIN. Thanks!